# TideSDK Debugging Crashes before I can Debug?

Tags: php, debugging, tidesdk

I've started working in TideSDK. So far I like it, with the exception of one thing:

If I get certain types of errors, it crashes and the console closes before I get a chance to read the output.

I'm using the latest version of the TideSDK (1.3.1 beta) and TideSDK Developer (1.4.2). However, whenever I get certain types of errors, my app is just like "I give up" and closes immediately, before I get a chance to check with the console to determine what the error was. There also seems to be no log, and I can't try...catch the error either.

I'm using the PHP module.

How can I properly debug these problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide specific details about the crash .. Isolating the code and providing small snippet of code which crashes would help anybody answer your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's the thing. I'm not just talking about one little thing that causes the crash. There are many things that cause crashes (just about any non-JavaScript error). The problem is, without the console remaining open, it is very difficult to debug what code is causing the crash in the first place. It doesn't provide a workable solution for development. In this case, I'm not looking for a fix to a particular problem. I'm looking for a fix to a workflow issue.